# No output for parsing google news content

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup, google-search, google-search-api

For my code here , I want to get the google new search title & URL .

It worked in the past .However , I don't know why it is not working now ?

Did Google change its CSS structure or what ?

Thanks

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {

        String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

        String search = "stackoverflow";

        String charset = "UTF-8";

        String news="&tbm=nws";


        String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)"; // Change this to your company's name and bot homepage!

        Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news).userAgent(userAgent).get().select( ".g>.r>.a");

        for (Element link : links) {
            String title = link.text();
            String url = link.absUrl("href"); // Google returns URLs in format "http://www.google.com/url?q=<url>&sa=U&ei=<someKey>".
            url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

            if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
                continue; // Ads/news/etc.
            }
            System.out.println("Title: " + title);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If the question is "how do I get the code working again?"
It would be difficult for anyone to know what the old page looked like unless they saved off a copy.

I broke down your select like this and it worked for me.

```
    String string = google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news;
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(string).userAgent(userAgent).get();
    Elements links = document.select( ".r>a");
```

The current page source looks like

```
       <div class="g">
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td valign="top" style="width:516px"><h3 class="r"><a href="/url?q=https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/marlboro-ransomware-defeated-in-one-day/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwis77iq7cDRAhXI7IMKHUAoDs0QqQIIFCgAMAE&amp;usg=AFQjCNFFx-sJdU814auBfquRYSsct2c8WA">Marlboro Ransomware Defeated in One Day</a></h3>
```

Results:
Title: Marlboro Ransomware Defeated in One Day
URL: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/marlboro-ransomware-defeated-in-one-day/

Title: Stack Overflow puts a new spin on resumes for developers
URL: https://techcrunch.com/2016/10/11/stack-overflow-puts-a-new-spin-on-resumes-for-developers/

Edited - Time range
These URL parameters look awful.
Add the suffix &tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A5%2F30%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A6%2F30%2F2016

But this part "min%3A5%2F30%2F2016" contains your minimum date.  5 30 2016.
min%3A + (month of year) + %2F + (day of month) + %2F + year 
And in "max%3A6%2F30%2F2016" is your maximum date.  6 30 2016.
max%3A + (month of year) + %2F + (day of month) + %2F + year

Here's the full URL searching for Mindy Kaling between 05/30/2016 and 06/30/2016
https://www.google.com/search?tbm=nws&q=mindy%20kaling&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A5%2F30%2F2016%2Ccd_max%3A6%2F30%2F2016

Comment: Works! One more question .How to get the news in a specific range of time ,e.g. one year ,three years  or five years ? Thanks

Comment: Updated answer to explain time range parameters

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me. Please note the pattern `".g .r>a"` - find elements with class `g` >>> all elements inside that with class `r` which is immediately descended with tag `a`

```
Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(search , charset) + news)
    .userAgent(userAgent).get().select( ".g .r>a");
```

From [documentation](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

> `.class`: find elements by class name, e.g. .masthead
>
> `ancestor child`: child elements that descend from ancestor, e.g. .body p finds p elements anywhere under a block with class "body"
>
> `parent > child`: child elements that descend directly from parent, e.g. div.content > p finds p elements; and body > * finds the direct children of the body tag

Though the solution worked, I guess relying on the same might not be recommended unless this is for study purpose or temporary use. Shipping this as a part of product might lead to failure anytime Google changes their page rendering.

Comment: that solved ,do u know how to set the date range as 2016/1/1 to 2016/1/12 and go to every pages of google search results

Comment: Running a search on Google gave me the URL pattern **?q=stackoverflow&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/2016,cd_max:12/1/2016&tbm=nws** would help you achieve this. Could you please accept the answer as it has solved your issue?